# How to use my own written library in C++ in eclipse (linux)?

Tags: c++, eclipse

Hey guys I have a problem, I want to use my own library in another C++ program.
I will describe what I do and then want to know what's wrong.

First I create a new C++ project as a static lib called "a". After that I create a new class called "aClass" with the following static method:

```
static int addTwo(int num);
```

Now I create a program that should use the created library. I make a new C++ project called "b" as a hello world project. Now I go to the options of this project and change the following:

- Add the include path of project "a" to project "b" so eclipse sees the aClass.h file
- I add the workspace of project "a" to the linker libraries
- I add the "a" to the libraries

Then I change my code of the main file in the "b" project and adds the header file of "a" and write a small line of code which should use a function of "a":

```
int i = aClass::addTwo(1);
```

When compiling with eclipse I get the following error:

```
Building target: b
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L"/home/barti/workspace/a" -o"b"  ./src/b.o   -la
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -la
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [b] Fehler 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution to your problem? I am having exactly the same issue and am not able to solve it!

Comment: Eclipse by default will place the output file in a folder named for the active build configuration, e.g. Debug; Change your library search path to include '/home/barti/workspace/a/Debug/'

Answer (score 0):

What is name of your lib file?

Is it liba.so?

Some time library build with ".a" or "so.1" kind of extension this may cause issue.

Try to do following

```
ln -s <current name> liba.so
```

Comment: Try to copy your lib (liba.a) in to "/usr/lib" or "/usr/local/lib" then execute command "ldconfig".

Answer (score 0):

Is the `liba.a` file actually present in `/home/barti/workspace/a`? I'm not familiar with C++ development using Eclipse, but GCC does not seem to find it in that directory (which was supposedly added to the link path by Eclipse).